# simulate hdmi/displayport "plug"/"unplug" event via command line

Tags: 20.04, xorg, display, i3-wm

I'm running two 4k monitors on `i3` (`regolith` variant) on `X` on `Ubuntu 20.04`.  Since initial install a couple months ago, I've had some frustrating issues around display; the most vexing issue is that:

- sometimes(1) when woken after sleep/lockscreen, one of my monitors is blank.  From the behavior of application windows on the remaining monitor, it appears as though it's unplugged or otherwise disabled.

The only thing I've found that works to fix besides rebooting is physically unplugging one of the DisplayPort cables, then re-plugging.

As such, that's my specific question (although feel free to suggest other routes I can persue) - what's the closest I can come to this via `bash` (or python)

Perhaps disable a port than re-enable?  Force a re-enumerate of some sort?  It's OK if it takes a number of seconds to run; it's a major PITA to do a reach-around on the monitors.  I can execute the script by switching over to a TTY and running the script (easy even though it's sideways, since the monitor that 'remains' is always the portrait one!)

Thanks!

1. seems vary per boot/uptime.  On some boots, it will never occur.  On others it occurs most times the monitors go to 'sleep'.  This is a development machine; typical uptime is around 1 week ~ 1 month.
2. FWIW i've dug through `journalctl` and `dmesg` logs looking for relevant errors, but haven't had any luck.
3. as mentioned there are some other issues, such as my monitor layout being broken after waking the box.  However, i have a simple `xrandr` script that easily solves that problem when it occurs.  That script does *NOT* work when the 2nd monitor is "off", only when it's in the wrong orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.  I resigned myself to unplugging and replugging frequently, and decided that I should get an adapter cable in order to avoid wearing out the displayport connection on my laptop.  I picked up a USB-C-to-HDMI adapter and connected to my monitor that way.  After all, cables and adapters are a lot cheaper than either laptops or monitors.

But it works just fine with the USB-C-to-HDMI adapter.  I no longer have to unplug and replug my monitor.  Solved by accident!  ;-)